# How to send text with multiple image whatsApp without save Number android

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I want to send text with image when number is not save.

This code is open WhatsApp but not show conversion specific number that is not save in contact list:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUriArray);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, (Serializable) stringBuffer);
intent.putExtra("jid", "91********" + "@s.whatsapp.net");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp.w4b");
startActivity(intent);
```

Please suggests how to send text with multiple image on specific number when  number is not save in contact list, jid work only save number but number is not save in contact jid is not working.